# When creating User attach standard role

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a User in my laravel 5.5 application like the following:

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       ]);
```

I am using a linking table `user_role` to add a role to a user.

In the past I have used `attach` to  add a role to a user  like the following:

```
   $user = new User();
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->password = $request['password'];
    $user->save();
    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
```

Any suggestions how to add  `attach` to the `User::create` function and attach a user with given standard role, when he registers?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between what you did and what the answer you marked as correct. What's wrong with your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `create` returns a user in case of successfully created one you can call `roles()` upon the method:

```
$user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
   ]);

$user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());

return $user
```

or

```
return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
   ])->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
```